# LongPress gesture doesn't work on iOS 5 and iOS 5.1 (but works on iOS 6)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, gestures

The following code doesn't work on iOS 5 and iOS 5.1 (but works on iOS 6):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)] autorelease];
    [myWebView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (void)handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
  ...
}
```

How to fix the issue? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You might try setting editSource.userInteractionEnabled = YES. Not sure it will help, but maybe something changed in iOS 6.

Comment: Already done on the xib-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)] autorelease];
    gesture.delegate = self;
    [myWebView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that this solved your issue.  No other GR requires that you register yourself as the delegate... adding a callback selector is typically sufficient... in fact, I just tested the code without adding the delegate in 5.1 and it worked fine for me.  I wonder what else might be happening in your environment to have caused this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
    longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 5;
    [longpressGesture setDelegate:self];
    [myWebView addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
    [longpressGesture release];

    - (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
        NSLog(@"longPressHandler");
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work without `(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`

Comment: it depends on content of the page (viewport or not maybe)